# texto não está aparecendo no slide show!

Tags: html, css

estou tentando inserir um texto na barra de gradient que é o rodape do meu slide show, mais ele não aparece. alguem pode me dizer o que está errado?

fiz uma pasta zip com os arquivos pra facilitar!
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1InzrGQ4hojkNwmCEVaYTsn3csurkW6l7

Comment: Ninguem vai fazer o download desse arquivo. Usa o post para meteres tudo o que é referente ao teu problema.

Comment: Cara quando for assim vc não precisa colocar os códigos do site inteiro. pode apenas colocar o código da parte envolvida no problema. Além disse a ferramente de texto para vc escrever sua pergunta tem opções para vc acrescentar o código etc. De qq forma veja a minha resposta que vc vai ver como resolver o problema do Slider. Tente colocar o código direto na pergunta na próxima ok, tmj

Comment: muito obrigado, deu certo. Entendido da proxima vez vou seguir as suas orientaçoes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara o seu problema é que vc está colocando o Texto como se fosse mais um slide. Então a div `<div class="slideinfo">` deve na verdade estar dentro de `<div class="slide">` Também fiz um ajuste de CSS apenas para ele ficar certinho dentro do mesmo.

Veja como ficou abaixo.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: helvetica;
 font-size: 12px;
}
.topo {
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #303030;
}
.topoint {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1040px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: auto;
}
.topoleft {
 width: 50%;
 height: 30px;
 float: left;
}
.toporight {
 width: 50%;
 height: 28px;
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
 margin-top: 2px;
}
.topoleft ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
}
.topoleft li {
 float: left;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 margin-left: 8px;
 margin-right: 8px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.topoleft li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFF;
}
.topoleft li .ativo {
 color: blue;
}
.topobusca {
 width: 110px;
 height: 26px;
 outline: 0;
}
.toporight a {
 float: right;
}
.toporight input {
 float: right;
}
.toporight img {
 margin-right: 4px;
}
.topo2 {
 height: 95px;
}
.topo2int {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1040px;
 height: 95px;
 margin: auto;
}
.logo {
 width: 230px;
 height: 65px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 30px;  
}
.topo2 .banner {
 width: 650px;
 height: 80px;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 7px;
 background-color: #ff0000;
}
.menu {
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #ff0000;
}
.menuint {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1040px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: auto;
}
.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: absolute;
}
.menu li {
 float: left;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 8px;
}
.menu li:hover .submenu {
 display: block;
}
.menu a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.submenu {
 width: 140px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ff0000;
 display: none;
}
.submenuitem {
 width: 140px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}
.submenuitem:hover {
       background-color: #ff5555;
       width: 130px;
}
.ultimasnoticias {
 height: 40px;
}
.ultimasnoticiasint {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1040px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: auto;
}
.ultnoticiasarea {
 height: 28px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
.ultnoticiastitulo {
 background-color: #ff0000;
 color: #fff;
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 2px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.ultnoticiasnoticia {
 color: #000;
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 2px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
.containerint  {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1040px;
 margin: auto;
}  
.leftside {
     width: 750px;
     float: left;
}
.rightside {
 width: 278px;
 min-height: 300px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 12px;
}
.widget {
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
.widget_titulo {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.widget_conteudo {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.noticia_item {
 font-size: 14px;
 margin:0px 10px;
 padding: 10px 0px;
 text-align: left;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.noticia_item a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
}
.slideshow {
 height: 335px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.slideshow_area {
  width: 10000px;
     height: 335px;
}
.slide {
 height: 335px;
 float: left;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
}
.slide img {
 height: 335px;
 width: 750px;
}
.slideinfo {
 position: relative;
    top: -70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url(../images/slideshow_bg.png);
    background-size: auto 70px;
    z-index: 10000;
    text-align: center;
}
.slideinfo_titulo {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #fff;
 top: 15px;
}
.slideimfo_subtitulo {
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Html Portal</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="topo">
    <div class="topoint">
       <div class="topoleft">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="./" class="ativo"> Home<a/></li>
              <li><a href="Quem somos">Quem Somos<a/></li>
              <li><a href="Anuncie aqui">Anuncie Aqui<a/></li>
              <li><a href="Contato">Contato<a/></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="toporight">
            <input type="image" border="0" src="images/lupabranca.png" width="26" height="26" >
            <input type="text" name="busca" class="topobusca" placeholder="Busca..." >
            <a href=""><img src="images/youtube.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/twitter.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/facebook.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/googleplus.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
            <a href=""><img src="images/rss.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="topo2">
       <div class="topo2int">
           <div class="logo">
             <img src="images/logo.jpg" border="0" width="230"/>
           </div>
           <div class="banner">
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
     <div class="menu">
      <div class="menuint">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="./" class="ativo">Home<a/></li>
          <li><a href="./" >Economia<a/></li>
          <li>
            <a href="./" >Entretenimento<a/>
            <img src="images/arrowdown.png" border="0" width="10"/>
              <div class="submenu">
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu1</div></a>
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu2</div></a>
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu3</div></a>
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu4</div></a>
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu5</div></a>
              </div>
            </li>
          <li> 
            <a href="./" >Esportes<a/>
            <img src="images/arrowdown.png" border="0" width="10">
              <div class="submenu">
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu1</div></a>
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu2</div></a>
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu3</div></a>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="./" >Geral<a/></li>
          <li>
            <a href="./" >Notícias<a/>
            <img src="images/arrowdown.png" border="0" width="10">
              <div class="submenu">
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu1</div></a>
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu2</div></a>
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu3</div></a>
                  <a href="./"><div class="submenuitem">submenu4</div></a>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="./" >policia<a/></li>
          <li><a href="./" >Videos<a/></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
       <div class="ultimasnoticias">
        <div class="ultimasnoticiasint">
          <div class="ultnoticiasarea">
             <div class="ultnoticiastitulo">ÚLTIMAS NOTÍCIAS</div>
             <div class="ultnoticiasnoticia">Alguma nótícia de algum texto que vai aparecer aqui...</div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="containerint">
            <div class="leftside">
                <div class="slideshow" id="slideshow">
                     <div class="slideshow_area">
                        <div class="slide">
                          <img src="http://placecage.com/200/200">
                          <div class="slideinfo">
                              <div class="slideinfo_titulo">Um tiulo de teste para esse slide</div>
                              <div class="slideinfo_subtitulo">Subtitulo de teste para esse slide</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide"><img src="images/jornal.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="slide"><img src="images/nfl.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="slide"><img src="images/champions.jpg"></div>
                        
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rightside">
                <div class="widget">
                   <div class="widget_titulo">SOCIAL</div>
                  <div class="widget_conteudo">
                        <a href=""><img src="images/youtube.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
                        <a href=""><img src="images/twitter.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
                        <a href=""><img src="images/facebook.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
                        <a href=""><img src="images/googleplus.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
                        <a href=""><img src="images/rss.png" border="0" width="26" height="26" /></a>
                  </div>
             </div>
                <div class="widget">
                   <div class="widget_titulo">ULTIMAS NOTÍCIAS</div>
                  <div class="widget_conteudo">
                      <div class="noticia_item">
                         <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                         aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                      </div>
                         <div class="noticia_item">
                         <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                         aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                      </div>
                       <div class="noticia_item">
                         <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                         aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                      </div>
                       <div class="noticia_item">
                         <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                         aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                      </div>
                       <div class="noticia_item">
                         <a href="./">Alguma notícia de algum site que vai
                         aparecer nesta parte do portal para exemplificar.<a/>
                      </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
                <div class="widget">
                   <div class="widget_titulo">PUBLICIDADADE</div>
                  <div class="widget_conteudo">
                      <img src="images/girl.jpg" border="0" width="275" >
                  </div>
             </div>
             <div class="widget">
                   <div class="widget_titulo">ENCONTRE-NOS NO FACEBOOK</div>
                  <div class="widget_conteudo">
                    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook&tabs&width=275&height=121&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="275" height="121" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```